# Can't boot Windows 10 past loading animation under Bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have a 2016 MBP with Sierra and have installed Windows 10 under Bootcamp. This has been running fine for a month or so but today I installed Docker in Windows and when it required a restart it restarted twice (both times requiring me to hold ALT to select Windows drive) and now does not get past the Windows 10 logo and cycling dots animation.

Do I need to reinstall Windows or will a USB bootable drive help? I have not created one yet.

TL;DR: I cannot get Windows 10 to boot past the loading animation after installing Docker in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinstall Windows just yet. Your boot files are fine, It wouldn't pass the first screen otherwise. The fact that you see the windows logo suggests the something (probably Docker, might be something else too) messed up your drivers.

Get into Windows safe mode and see if you can Uninstall Docker, if that doesn't work, check if you have a restore point to before the install.

Comment: I've been trying to get into Safe Mode but not sure how. As I do not have function keys and can't initiate it from inside windows I do not know how to get to it.

Comment: How do I get into Windows safe mode?

Comment: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10 Option 3

Comment: Thanks, but none of those options work with Bootcamp.