# How to get into Windows 10 Safe Mode on 2016 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, safe-mode

I'm told I need to get into Windows 10's Safe Mode running under Boot Camp, but I'm on a Mac Book Pro, 2016 model, which does not have function keys at start up.

How can I force Safe Mode for Windows 10 on the most recent MBP?

Previous Question: [Can't boot Windows 10 past loading animation under Bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273512/cant-boot-windows-10-past-loading-animation-under-bootcamp)

Comment: Are you able to boot normally - or is this your problem ??

Comment: Maybe read here: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/start-windows-10-in-safe-mode-boot-advanced-options-f8-exit-3421988/

Comment: Windows 10 sits with the spinning dots, unable to get to the login screen. I don't have a USB recovery drive.

Comment: Windows 10 will automatically drop to the internal recovery if you hard shut down 3 times at a failed boot. [I've never tried this on Boot Camp, only on actual PCs] Safe mode, btw, is Shift, not an f-key.

Comment: Neither option works under Bootcamp. Tried hard shutdown during start up 5 times. Couldn't get it to kick into recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while booting up or restarting.

This assumes that Windows is your default startup disk.
Microsoft changed how to get into Safe Mode on Windows 10. [From Microsoft.com:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode)

> Restart your PC. When you get to the sign-in screen, hold the Shift
> key down while you select Power Power icon
>
> > Restart. After your PC restarts to the Choose an option screen, select Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Startup Settings > Restart.
> > After your PC restarts, you'll see a list of options. Select 4 or F4
> > to start your PC in Safe Mode. Or if you'll need to use the Internet,
> > select 5 or F5 for Safe Mode with Networking.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I needed to boot into safe mode or access other Windows recovery options, but couldn't because my Mac had the touch bar and for some reason my trackpad and keyboard would not work when booting into Windows, at all. After learning that Windows should automatically boot into recovery mode if there have been 4-5 hard reboots (assuming Bootcamp is your main startup disk), I tried hard resetting (holding the power button down until it shuts down, then pushing the power button to turn it on) several times.

On top of that, considering my trackpad and keyboard would not work when booting into Windows, I instead hard rebooted while holding down the Option button, which brought up the Mac and Bootcamp (Windows) partitions, where my trackpad and keyboard worked. Then, I held down the shift button while I clicked on the Bootcamp (Windows) partition "arrow" button. That booted Windows into recovery mode, which gave me the options I needed and I was able to fix what I needed to.

This may have been a combination of just being lucky (a fluke) with the amount of times I tried hard rebooting and thinking of holding down Shift while clicking on the Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable USB key using the Windows Media Installation Tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and boot from it on your Mac.

I just finished going through this, and fixed it. It was a pain because you can't run the tool on a Mac, so you must run the tool on a spare PC. I was on vacation, and didn't have one until I got home. My Windows 10 boot up was stuck at the blue logo.

Once you re-start the Mac with the USB drive created by the tool, hold down the Option Key, and you'll see the USB option EFI Boot.

When that starts, select 'Repair your computer,' NOT 'Install Windows' > Troubleshoot > Startup Repair

That worked for me... Don't forget to keep that USB drive around :)